# Displaying contact form under categories

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, xml, contact-form

I am not much familiar with many feature of magento but I know that to display form, we can use the following in pages.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

but I have a requirement that needs me to put it under categories, how can I use the same code under "custom layout update" or code it in my template.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala where should i use that code?

Comment: in your `/app/design/frontend/my_mod/default/layout/layout.xml`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala great, now when i submit my form, it says 404. Do i need to setup something in order to use form?

Comment: What url you get in for form action ? please check and tell me

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala `/contacts/index/post`

Comment: I update my answer with base url please do and let me knoew and if my answer help you then mark as accepted , so other user who face the same issue take benifit from that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45693/discussion-between-nofel-and-murtuza-zabuawala).

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for display in category layout update you can use below code , please try and let me know if its not working.

```
  <catalog_category_default>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml" >
        <action method="setFormAction">
          <form_action>{{baseUrl}}"/contacts/index/post"</form_action>
        </action>
    </block> 
</reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

and also write same code for

```
  <catalog_category_layered>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml" >
        <action method="setFormAction">
          <form_action>{{baseUrl}}"/contacts/index/post"</form_action>
        </action>
    </block> 
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

If you are using in your cms page then

Change your cms page like this

```
 {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm"  template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

and open your `contacts/form.phtml` file and change your action method like this

```
  action = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl();?>contacts/index/post '
```

Comment: I didn't work I pasted in under my module `/app/design/frontend/my_mod/default/layout/layout.xml`

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I have updated my answer